# Refering a class in a static method

Tags: java, static, this

Is there a way to refer java to the current class in a static method? I usually use the word "this", but this is obviously not working.. Any help?

Comment: `this` refers to the current **instance**. So, no way, obviously.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information, why you need the current class?

Comment: Can't be done.  You'll need to actually give the name of the class.

Answer (score 3):

`this` points to the current *instance*, not the current *class*.

For this reason, `this` will never work in a `static` context.

If you want to use the current class, you'll have to explicitly name it as `MyClass`.